# Fetching data from network without directly update UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-networking

I'm building an `Android` app that should draw a chart : Combo Chart.

For this issue I connect to a `Web Service` through `SOAP request` and getting `SOAP object` - `Array` with objects (like `Point` type) that represent how the chart should be created.
I have a function that build this chart from the data I transfer to it (List of `Points`).

My question is: What is the best choose for getting this data `asynchronous` and saving it on a `List` parameter. I know I have the `AsynTask` , `Threads`, `Service`...

What is the best choose, consider that I don't need to update directly the result to `UI`, I only need to fetch data,in the end get any kind of trigger that the network work is done, then save it locally and transfer this parameter to the right function.

Answer (score 0):

Since its short background task choose `AsyncTask`which if you want to change it later to touch the UI this will give you a lot of options.
plus it handles memory allocations and Grabage collection.

Comment: If I should touch the UI so I agree, but for know I just need to pass it to other function, is it still the right thing to do?

Comment: even tought u dont need to touch UI the advantage of AysncTask is the onPostExecute which sits on the MainThread so you can send it to any functions regardless to which function plus Thread or Service is for long backgrounds task and its not include sending data or fetching data from Server its more like Socket open per Application or listen to Server for Notifaction while your not inside the Application

Comment: So in onPostExecute I should call to function that update the UI and pass the data from doInBackground()?

Comment: yep. PostExecute() can take the data from doInBackground and also called the UIThread.